# A Minimum cut and maximum flows in a network

Tags: graph-theory

For a network $ N $with capacity function  $c$ and minimum cut $ [X,X']$ in $N $.

If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are flows in the network that agree on $[X,X']$ and $[X',X]$ , does it imply that these two flows are maximum ? And how about the converse .

Comment: The zero flow agrees with itself everywhere, but it is generally not maximal. Are you sure you're asking what you really mean to ask?

Comment: @GerryMyerson what does "agree" mean here ?

Comment: @Frank, a flow in a network is a function from the arcs in the network to the nonnegative real numbers (and satisfying certain properties). I use the word "agree" (and I assume hali uses it the same way) to mean that the two flows, restricted to the arcs in question, agree as functions.

Comment: So, hali, do you wish to clarify your question?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson , maybe one direction is clearly false but what about the converse ? If they are maximal should they agree ?

Comment: *Maybe* one direction is clearly false? You're not convinced? What would it take to convince you? For the converse, you should try to find a network with two very different maximal flows (and correspondingly different minimal cuts) – it's not that hard to do.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson , The minimum cuts one should be $[X,X']$ and the other cut should be $[X',X]$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Gerry Merson , how about a drawing ? :) .To clarify your second to last comment .

Comment: Sure, a drawing would be great, and I'm sure you can make one. But let's settle one thing first: are you, or are you not, convinced that the one direction is false?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson , yes.

Comment: So, have you had any luck finding a network with two different maximal flows?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson , I solved it . :)

Comment: Good. Then let me encourage you to write up what you found, and to post it as an answer.